# JMeter - Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException Response message

Tags: jmeter

Recorded Blazemeter scripts are not working in JMeter, getting following error message.

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that JMeter fails to receive the response most probably due to network error (connection has been terminated or timed out)

In order to get more information you should [increase JMeter Logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

it would also be a good idea to [enable network debugging on Java level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html), it can be done by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

and you should get way more information in [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)), this way you will get the error reason and would be able to handle it.

It worth also checking:

- that your application is not overloaded as it might be the case the application cannot handle the load delivered by JMeter hence fails to respond properly
- if you're absolutely sure that the application works normally and the problem is at JMeter end you can follow workarounds from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page